# TF31003: Either you have not entered the necessory credentials or your user account does not have permission to connect to the Team Foundation Server

Tags: vb.net

i had an error like this. I tried many things like clearing cookies in IE, checking my credentials but still i can't connect to the server. I also tried different suggestions that i found on Google but still i can't connect. I'm using cisco vpn connect to our server and i'm using Visual studio 2010 installed in my Windows 10 Laptop. I can connect to the server if i use my another laptop with windows 7 and VS 2010 installed.

Thank you very Much.

Comment: This question is better off over at [**Server Fault**](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution. I just check my windows credentials. What i did is i matched the credentials from my old laptop to the new. Then i worked. Thanks